# Access single collection in Multi-Thread Process

Tags: java, multithreading

I've having one question regarding multi threading.

If I create a single collection (HasMap or list etc ) and access same collecion in Multi threads (5) process, Will it work?

Not much aware of Java multithreading coding style.

Comment: Why DonwVote .. ? :(

Comment: First at all, could you please add a piece of code on what do you think to do? because we don't know if the how the `map` or `list` will be used, instantiated, how many classes will use, then we can give advice to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` if you need very high concurrency in your project which uses thread safe without synchronizing  or  `SynchronizedHashMap` which uses synchronization from a object level that returns a iterator which fails-fast on concurrent modification.

Comment: That depends on how you use the collection. Concurrency is complicated and I recommend reading some tutorials (e.g. [Lesson: Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)), books (e.g. _Java Concurrency in Practice_), and the documentation of Java's concurrency framework (e.g. [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) and sub-packages) in order to familiarize yourself with the concept. What you need to ensure is that the appropriate _happens-before_ relationships are created.

Comment: If a collection is not thread-safe, then it is the responsibility of the client to control access to its state in such a manner that the class' invariants and post-conditions always hold true.

Comment: In general, no, it will not work, you will have to take precautions to make it thread-safe. Are you doing both reads and writes or only reads?

Answer (score 1):

If you populate that collection once before starting threads and then all threads only read from collection then yes, simple collection will work. But if some of your threads put/add data into collection and some read it then you either need to use thread safe collection (like `ConcurrentHashMap` or sumply `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())`) or use additional synchronization like `synchronized` blocks and/or `Lock` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are still exploring multi-threading, I am assuming that you are talking java.util.XXX instead of java.util.concurrent.XXX. Always remember ConcurrentModificationException while dealing with java.util collections which are NOT thread safe. If you are not modifying a collection and just reading, then no issues. But if modification is happening in one of the threads, you may get ConcurrentModificationException exception.

Try below code:

```
package my.package.concurrency_practice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionsAndThreads {
    private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public CollectionsAndThreads() {
        for (int i=0; i < 10_000_000; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Initialized with one million entries.");
    }

    public void addEntries() {

        System.out.print("Adding a million more entries ... ");
            for (int i = 10_000_001; i < 20_000_000; i++) {
                list.add(i);
            }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    public void interateEntries() {
        Iterator iter = list.iterator();

        System.out.print("Interating through entries ... ");

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                iter.next();
            }
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CollectionsAndThreads test = new CollectionsAndThreads();

        System.out.println(test.getList().size());

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside thread: " + this.toString());
                test.addEntries();
            }
        });

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Inside thread: " + this.toString());
                test.interateEntries();
            }
        });

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
}
```

Did you get java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Now that answers your query. How to make above code thread safe? You explore that :-)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you are going to do.
Manipulating the List ? 
Removing elements ? 
Is the list temporary ? 
Is it read Only for 4 Threads an only one thread adds something ?